# installing Apache and PHP

Tags: php, windows, apache-2.2

please help with Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.3.3
I have to do

```
LoadModule php5_module "c:/php/php5apache2.dll"
```

but I don't have any "c:/php/php5apache2.dll" on disk

I installed PHP in C:\php

[image]

Comment: You might wish to try XAMPP or WAMP, which will install everything for you. There are tons of hits on Google for 'c:/php/php5apache2.dll', by the way.

Comment: @Frankie exactly this firs google article tells me about this  "c:/php/php5apache2.dll" but **I don't have it** in the php installation folder

Comment: The first hit on Google suggest that you might wish to look for php5apache2_5.dll instead.

Comment: @Alex: don't have php5apache2_5.dll neither. I don't need MySQL and Perl, just Apache+php

Comment: Sure, but even if it installed MySQL and Perl, but configured PHP and Apache correctly, you could ignore those and use what you need... unless you're short on disk space, I guess!

Comment: @Alex: I son't like installing soft I don't need.

Comment: @serhio this may or may not be the answer... but take a look into http://www.zubair.info/2010/04/15/apache-2-2-x-wont-load-php5apache2-dll-solution.html all I did was google up the file name

Comment: @Frankie mister google, thank you, but I included an image, that displays you the absence of dlls with apache in the name, and the page you gave to me is for Linux.

Comment: I don't like installing software I don't need either, but I dislike having software I have installed not work at all, too,  because I don't have it configured correctly. So, it's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

You probably downloaded VC9 instead of VC6 on [windows.php.net](http://windows.php.net/download/).

You can read in the download instructions:

> "If you are using PHP with Apache 1 or
>   Apache2 from apache.org you need to
>   use the VC6 versions of PHP. [...] Do
>   NOT use VC9 version with apache.org
>   binaries."

Comment: yes... I dowloaded VC9, because is was the first one

Comment: So, I downloaded the V6... I have the same c:\php content... any \*apache\*.dll

Comment: That's odd, because I downloaded it myself (both TS and NTS) and both have php5apache.dll. TS also has php5apache2.dll and php5apache2_2.dll.

Comment: @netcoder do you have that dlls installed in what folder?

Answer (score 0):

what I would recommend it to download something called wamp, an acronym for Windows Apache MySql PHP. It is great, I use it all the time and It is free.

[WAMP](http://tinyurl.com/24u9qyu)